# Only want to fill in top and bottom row of 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I only want to fill in the top and bottom row of an uninitialised array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == (ROWS - 1)) {
            values[i][j] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I do so, it fills in all the rows in between with 0:

```
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
4444444444
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: The others are default values

Comment: 0 is default value to integer arrays in java. It wouldn't make sense to have an array with NULL integers just doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access only the top and bottom rows explicitly:

```
for (int i=0; i < ROWS; i+=ROWS-1) {
    for (int j=0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
        values[i][j] = i;
    }
}
```

This avoids iterating every row unnecessarily.  Note that the zeroes you are seeing may be the default value for an `int` array.

Answer (score 2):

The default value for any `int` in Java is zero (0). So any that are left unset will have this value. This is the case whether it's a single `int` or an array of them. The consequence of this is that the rows which are untouched by your code contain zeroes.